# In Java, what is the "char" for a tab and how do I pass through a "Charset"?

Tags: java, csv

These are probably really basic questions but I'm stumped. Everywhere I read says "\t" is the escape sequence for a tab but I need a char. I also tried to create the chartset as "new Charset("UTF-8");" but I get the error "Cannot instantiate the type Charset"

I'm trying to use the following library in my program to output a CSV tab delimited file. The function requires the following parameters.

public CsvWriter(String fileName, char delimiter, Charset charset)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Writingdelimitedtextdatatoafileorastream.htm

Thank you so much!

Comment: Class `Charset` is `abstract`, that is why you can't create an instace of it by calling `new Charset(...)`.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `char tab = '\t';`?

Comment: Well I feel dumb. I for some reason believed that a char must only be 1 character when typed out. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The tab character is `\t`.

The [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) type provides a `static` field that holds a reference to a [UTF-8 `Charset` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8). You can also use

```
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding something.

A `Charset` is not a character at all. It is a Java object which embodies two things: a character decoding process, and a character encoding process.

The decoding process turns a sequence of `byte`s into a sequence of `char`s; the encoding process does the reverse. Unicode calls this a "character encoding". The most commonly used, and by far, is UTF-8 (UTF stands for "Unicode Transformation Format").

It is necessary to specify that to the CSV reader constructor because the contents of the file are, ultimately, bytes; the CSV reader needs to know how it will decode these bytes into `char`s, therefore it needs to be told which decoding process to use, and in Java, this means passing it a `Charset` object.

For more information, see [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) and [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html).

As to what the tab character constant is, you have been told the answer already so this will not be repeated here.